# Why two routers connected via PPP don't use ARP but Ethernet requires ARP?

Tags: router, protocol-theory, layer2, arp, layer3

I have read from [@Ron Maupin's answer of this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/36605/when-exactly-is-arp-protocol-is-used/36609)   that your two routers are connected via PPP (this is not uncommon), ARP will not be used  , but if the two routers are connected via ethernet, then ARP will be used. My  question are that -

**(A)** What does the mean two router connected by PPP(point to protocol)?  As per as my understanding two routers are directly connected.

**(B)** Why if the two routers connected by PPP then ARP doesn't required?

**(C)** What does the mean that the two routers are connected via ethernet?   As per as my understanding in between two routers there exists any layer2 device like switch or bridge.

**(D)** Why if the two routers connected via ethernet then ARP is required?

**(E)** If the two routers are directly connected then they can be communicated via IP address or Mac address or both?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129951/discussion-on-question-by-alok-maity-why-two-connected-routers-via-ppp-isnt-use).

Comment: Names refer to specific things. When you see PPP, don't assume that because you know what "point-to-point" means you know everything about PPP — look it up!

Comment: @Ron ARP is used for ipv4 to know the Mac address in layer2. But NDP is used for ipv6 in layer3 to know about Mac address in layer 3?

Comment: No. NDP has a feature that works like ARP, but it uses multicast instead of broadcast (interrupts _everything_) that IPv6 does not have. NDP sends the request to a special multicast group that is based on the last 24-bits of the layer-3 address to which the target is subscribed. Multicasts only interrupt those listening on the group address, and that is probably only the target host, so multicast is less disruptive to the network.

Comment: @Ron Maupin then l3 multicast isn't happening in l3 but it converts into l2 multicasting and multicast happening in l2 by Mac address?

Comment: MAC addressing has a special multicast OUI. For IPv4 it is `01:00:5e`, and it must append the last 23 bits of the layer-3 multicast address (there are 28 unique bits in an IPv4 layer-3 multicast, so there are 32 IPv4 layer-3 multicast addresses that correspond to a MAC multicast address). The MAC OUI for IPv6 multicast is `33:33:xx`. There is a special format for NDP solicited not multicasts. See [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/29029/8499) and its comments with links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **(A) What does the mean two router connected by PPP(point to protocol)? As per as my understanding two routers are directly connected.**

Routers (or any nodes) *may* be connected using PPP. PPP uses an underlying simple serial interface like RS-232 and provides data link layer functionality required by IP (data framing).

> **(B) Why if the two routers connected by PPP then ARP doesn't required?**

These interfaces are point-to-point and use no addressing, so there's no use for ARP.

For completeness: The PPP framing specification ([RFC 1662](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1662#section-3.1)) *does* include an 8-bit address field, but since L2 addressing is not used (the framing is borrowed from HDLC), that address field is specified as a constant 0xff:

> **3.1.  Frame Format**
>
> ...
>
> Address Field
>
> The Address field is a single octet, which contains the binary
> sequence 11111111 (hexadecimal 0xff), the All-Stations address.
> Individual station addresses are not assigned.  The All-Stations
> address MUST always be recognized and received.

Accordingly, a PPP frame with any other address is invalid.

> **(C) What does the mean that the two routers are connected via ethernet?**

Routers may be connected via Ethernet with a point-to-point link (simple cable) or using switches. In any case, Ethernet is a point-to-multipoint network, requiring proper MAC addressing.

> **(D) Why if the two routers connected via ethernet then ARP is required?**

ARP is only used for *IPv4 over MAC-based networks*, most prominently Ethernet/IEEE 802.3 or IEEE 802.11.

MAC-based networks require the protocol on top to specify the desired destination MAC address for their payload. IPv4 uses ARP with a broadcast address to learn that destination MAC.  Then it uses the underlying network as L2 to deliver its packet.

You cannot run PPP on top of such a point-to-multipoint network, but there may be special variants like PPPoE.

PPPoE creates another L2 on top of Ethernet's L2, but there's no addressing between PPPoE and IP still (PPPoE uses MAC addressing downwards with Ethernet, ie. Ethernet's MAC addressing is controlled by PPPoE, not IP).

> **(E) If the two routers are directly connected then they can be communicated via IP address or Mac address or both?**

Any nodes using IP use underlying data link layer (L2) protocols for local communication. The L2 protocol can vary along an IP path. Ethernet includes the required L2 protocol, a serial link requires PPP, (obsolete) SLIP or something similar.

Basically, routers communicate at the network layer (L3), using IP addresses. As pointed out above, they also need to use proper L2 addressing on certain networks, hence the need for ARP for IPv4 or IPv6's NDP as 'glue'.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129971/discussion-on-answer-by-zac67-why-the-two-connected-routers-via-ppp-doesnt-use).

Comment: @Zac If "there's no addressing between PPPoE and IP still "- how layer2 and layer3 will be communicated?

Comment: @AlokMaity We've [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129969/discussion-between-zac67-and-alok-maity).

Answer (score 1):

This question is kinda impossible to answer. Different protocols use different means of transmitting its data.

OSPF uses IP, RIP uses IP/UDP, IS-IS uses layer2 directly. Also, addresses on multicast-capable links are different.

(A) and (B) are already answered.

> (C) What does the mean that two routers are connected via ethernet? As per as my understanding in between two routers there exists any layer2 device like switch or bridge.

I think it means that the interfaces are Ethernet. Switches may or may not be there. The significance of Ethernet over PPP is that there may be multiple devices connected (e.g., with switches) and they can be reached using broadcast/multicast capabilities of Ethernet.

> (D) Why if two routers connected via ethernet then ARP is required?

If the packet is sent over IP and is sent to a unicast IP (i.e., IP of another interface) as a destination, "normal" procedure for sending packet over Ethernet with ARP should happen.

Note, that for routing protocol packets this is a very big "IF". Most packets will be sent to broadcast or multicast addresses.

For normal forwarded packets (with payload) this holds.

> (E) If two routers are directly connected then they can communicate via IP address or Mac address or both?

Two (directly connected) routers in the end always communicate via layer2 protocol of their link. That is, layer2 processing should be present on each interface. Each routing protocol decides what other protocols to stack on top of layer2. Note however, that when talking about routing protocol packets, in most cases* IP is sort of "dummy". It has addresses, but routers cannot yet route based on these addresses. It can only forward packet to the next direct hop.

<sup>This is not entirely true, some protocols allow to use IP addresses for non-direct neighbors (e.g. virtual links in OSPF), but they describe a procedure how this is accomplished using already computed routes.</sup>

Comment: But my question is that any two router connected in network layer in one side suppose sender side, it has not come yet data link layer. Then how they are communicated?

Comment: sorry, i do not understand that sentence because of the language. could you rephrase it?

Comment: Suppose Host A wants to communicate with B. A has already crossed the it's application , transport layer. Now A comes in network layer. Now network layer has two router which are connected. My question how the two router communicated? Now presently A is in sender side in network layer, never enter it's data link layer.

Comment: Is the question - how A knows which router to send data to?

Comment: The communication always goes down the whole stack. Once the communication reaches layer 3, layer 3 determines outgoing interface/next hop for the packet. Then, the communication goes into that interface's layer 2 for the interface/next hop with appropriate layer 2 processing. Then layer 2 passes its frame to layer 1 and data is physically sent over wire/air/whatever it is.

Comment: My question how the two router communicated in network layer in sender side A? By ip address or Mac address

Comment: my question how is it possible in network layer use of Mac address (data link layer) and physical layer?

Comment: what do you mean by "router communicate"? do you mean how they exchange routing information, or how the packet from A is forwarded?

Comment: suppose two router using DVR and they in layer3 in sender side. They don't reach data link layer till now in sender side. When they want exchange information they have to broadcast. So my question they using layer2 broadcast? Means first router stacked down from network layer, data link, physical layer to second router physical layer and data Linklayer. And in data link layer broadcast has done. Am I correct?

Comment: routers have interfaces. routers are connected to other routers through interfaces Each interface has a layer 1 and 2 associated with it. To send a packet from one interface to another router needs to perform layer 2 processing (for Ethernet, this requires determining which MAC addresses to use in the packet). Control plane needs to determine on what interfaces to send packet. This is protocol-specific and cannot be answered in general. DVR protocols are RIP, EIGRP, BGP (path vector is distance vector)  and Babel. They do not work the same.

Comment: my is in DVR router is broadcasting in layer3 or switch  in layer2 is broadcasting?

Comment: doing anything in layer 3 requires functioning layer 3. Routing protocol, which is there to build a functioning layer 3 cannot do anything that requires functioning layer 3. Routing protocol can use anything, that layer 2 can provide. So, if the packet has a broadcast destination IP  address, then it is mapped to a broadcast layer 2 address and  layer 2 is doing the broadcast.  Whatever router does inside its control plane, which may or may not be called by similar names, is not layer 3 broadcast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129955/discussion-between-alok-maity-and-effie).

Comment: That means in DVR router using broadcasting and layer2 switch helps to broadcasting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129961/discussion-between-alok-maity-and-effie).